# Can we improve this Dockefile

Tags: docker

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
ENV app_environment="prod" 
ARG app_dir
RUN echo ${app_dir}
COPY filecopytest.txt ${app_dir}/filecopy.txt
WORKDIR /
CMD ["sh"]
```

When I try to run `docker build --build-arg app_dir="app_dir_arg" --tag arg_env:1.0 --file arg_env .`, it is throwing this error:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (1/2)
 => [internal] load build definition from arg_env                                                                                     0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                    0.0s 
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount7787963245/arg_env: no such 
file or directory`.
```

In my present directory, I have a `Dockerfile` and a txt file named `filecopytest.txt`.

Comment: Try issuing the build command without `--file arg_env`.

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. I recommend [edit]ing the post and rewording the title.

Comment: `--file arg_env` So do you have a file named `arg_env`?

Comment: Your dockerfile is named `Dockerfile`, not `arg_env`, right ? If you pass `--file arg_env` you're telling the builder to look for yml inside the filename `arg_env`, which you don't have, and therefore you get the error.

Comment: @Niloct, on this line `COPY filecopytest.txt ${app_dir}/filecopy.txt` in the `Dockerfile`, does the `filecopy.txt` represent a new file being created within the specified directory inside the container?

Comment: Yes, it considers the last `WORKDIR` before the `COPY` command, `/` if no `WORKDIR` is present. Read this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir